# How to load and process 2 images at a time

Tags: python, opencv

I have 20 images in a folder.

I want to load first two images and process, then load the next two images and process and so on.

I want to know how to achieve this in python openCV

Sequence to follow; Load image 1, 2 > process (i will do this bit), then load image 2, 3 > process, 3, 4 > process, 4,5 > process...so on

Comment: please post, what you have tried

Comment: Please clarify what the actual problem is, else folk just waste their time speculating. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know if you just want to process them 2 by 2 or 2 at the same time so here is both!

**Process 2 by 2 sequentially:**

```
import os
import cv2

files = os.listdir('<image_folder>')

for i in range(0, len(files), 2):
    image1 = cv2.imread(files[i])
    image2 = cv2.imread(files[i+1])

    process(image1)
    process(image2)
```

**Process 2 at the same time:**

A useful tool is the `map` function in python's multiprocessing library. It's actually very simple to use, example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


p = Pool(2)

for i in range(0, len(files), 2):
    p.map(process, [cv2.imread(files[i]),
                    cv2.imread(files[i+1])])
```

The list holds your elements and you're trying to apply function process to each of those elements in parallel. `p.map` will do that for you no problem!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you...multiprocessing is what I was looking for. it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob2
import cv2

images = glob2.glob('imageFolder/*.jpg')

images = list(zip(images, images[1:] + images[:1]))

for item in images:
    img1 = cv2.imread(item[0])
    img2 = cv2.imread(item[1])

    #process here
```